# Minimising risk of a portfolio(set of stocks) if I know correlation values for all pairs of stocks in the set.

Tags: statistics, correlation

I came up with a conjecture, any ideas to prove or disprove it?

I have 5 different stocks: A, B, C, D, E

I have the correlation values for all combinations in the set. I need to make sure that the "net correlation" of the system is minimized.

To do that I will solve the following system:

A*B*CORREL(A,B) = A*C*CORREL(A,C) = A*D*CORREL(A,D) = B*C*CORREL(B,C) = B*D*CORREL(B,D) = C*D*CORREL(C,D)

Is that correct?

Also, is "net correlation" a thing?

Comment: If you've not come across it yet, I'd suggest looking into Markowitz portfolio theory --- it answers such questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's wrong.  I think what you mean is something like this.  You will buy $x_i$ worth of stock $i$,  with $x_1 + \ldots + x_5 = 1$ (say).  The return per dollar on stock $i$ is $R_i$, with covariances $\text{Cov}(R_i, R_j)$.  You want to minimize the variance in the total return, namely

$$\text{Var}\left( \sum_i x_i R_i \right) = \sum_{i,j} x_i x_j \text{Cov}(R_i, R_j)$$

Assume you have a solution where all $x_i > 0$ (or that you can buy negative amounts).  Using a Lagrange multiplier we look at $$ F(x_1, \ldots, x_5, \lambda) = \sum_{i,j} x_i x_j \text{Cov}(R_i, R_j) + \lambda \left(1 - \sum_i x_i\right)$$

EDIT: Taking derivative with respect to $x_i$ gives you the conditions

$$ 2 \sum_j x_j \text{Cov}(R_i, R_j) - \lambda = 0 $$

Thus if ${\bf x}^T = (x_1, \ldots, x_5)$, ${\bf e}^T = (1, \ldots, 1)$, 
and $C$ is the covariance matrix with entries $\text{Cov}(R_i, R_j)$, 
$$ {\bf x} = \frac{\lambda}{2} C^{-1} {\bf e} $$

Comment: Instead of Covariance, I am working with Correlation.

Comment: Correlation = Covariance divided by product of standard deviations.  I suggest you work with covariance: its mathematical properties are much nicer.

Comment: Thanks for the help, can you suggest how would I go about solving the real world problem (considering I know all the covariance values)

Comment: If you have the constraint that only nonnegative amounts are allowed, it's a quadratic programming problem.  I might use Cplex or Maple.

Comment: If not, Maple, Matlab or Mathematica can do the linear algebra.